# AD 2016 share per person

Tags: active-directory, network-share, windows-10, windows-server-2016

I am very new to windows server 2016 or any other one so don't hate. I am trying to setup a ad directory domain that will mount a drive for the user that logged in. Until now I only got the logging in working. I haven't got the user drive working. I have no clue how to tackle this. Until now I have tried. 
Group policy script to mount share 
Group policy network drive mapping 
AD user properties drive

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thank You!!

Answer (score 1):

First off your user's share has to exist.

Create the share on server.  Decide if you want the share hidden or not and then name it.  I would personally go with `\\server\users` or `\\server\users$` depending on if you want it hidden or not.  You will need to set the share permissions and the file system ACL (or NTFS permissions).  The the share permissions I give "Everyone" full control and then scope down the permissions via the ACL.  As best as I can recall you will need to give "Authenticated Users" the "List Folder Contents" right if you are going to have Macs connect to the users share (although it has been a very long time since I have dealt with Macs).

After you have this setup then you can create the folder for the user.  I would suggest using the user's SAMAccountName for their user space folder.  You will need to assign them rights to their folder.  I suggest giving them modify as opposed to full access, but do what best suits your needs or requirements.

Then in Active Directory under profile for your user(s) you can select connect for home folder and have  `\\server\users\%LogonUser%` and this should get their personal share connected the next time they login.

Also make sure you test and your permissions are correct so users cannot browse into another's share space.